# Displaying error results first in foreach loop?

Tags: php

What is the best way to display errors within a foreach loop first? Right now I am reading through a list and separating the info using preg_match. How can I go through the results and output the error'd results first and then show the rest of them?

Here is a general idea of what I am thinking it would look like however I think this way will still output them in order

```
$mids = explode("\n", $_POST['invoiceCheck']);
foreach ($mids as $mid){
     if(!empty($mid)) {
          //Check for errors using mysqli
          if(error) {
               //Show error result
               //Show error result
               //Show error result
          } else {
               //Rest of results
     }
}
```

INPUT

```
890 hello blah
012 random blah
123 test blah
345 stack blah
567 over blah
```

OUTPUT

```
ERROR DUPLICATE: 123 already exists with test
ERROR PARTIAL DUPLICATE: 567 already exists but with different name
890 hello blah
012 random blah
345 stack blah
```

The results error'd out because they already exist in my database. Do I need to assign an error to them using an array and then re-sort that array to get the output?

Comment: Since we are in pseudocodeland: `if(error){ //don't show error yet, store it somewhere to show later} else { //don't show item yet, store it to show after displaying errors; }`

Comment: Why not just display any errors right away in your `if(error)` clause, and if there's no error, store the value in a temporary array, then loop through that array once your `foreach` loop finishes to display the non-error values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is display the errors before the items that don't generate an error, you could do that like this:

```
$mids = explode("\n", $_POST['invoiceCheck']);
$noErrors = [];  //array to store items that don't generate an error

// ----- loop through all items and print any errors -----

foreach ($mids as $mid){
    if(!empty($mid)) {
        //Check for errors using mysqli
        if(error) {
            //display error
            echo $errorMsg  //replace this with your error message
        } else {
            //add value to array to display later
            $noErrors[] = $mid;
        }
    }
}

// ----- print any items that didn't generate an error -----

foreach ($noErrors as $item) {
    //display each non-error item
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed to do